# Stars symbol in FEN

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

> How to put stars symbol in FEN notation? I can not do it in the DiagTransfer 3.0.1.

[image]

> I wrote (without the stars):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\centering
\newchessgame[setfen=8/8/8/8/4K3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1]
\showboard

\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does start mean and how do you present it in algebraic notation?

Comment: You can use the chessboard package to create new symbols. On page 73 of the documentation there is an example. This chars will work in fen too but you can't "play" with them: `\mainline` etc will not like them as it will not know how to move them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I noticed two issues regarding the documentation of your excellent package. Since I didn't know where to write them, I'm doing it here (apology to OP). Firstly the official documentation on [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak) seems to be somehow incomplete (e.g. there is no page 73). Also, today in an attempt to answer this question I did a `texdoc xskak` in MacTeX 2013 and it did not show up the pdf documentation. However, it did show the read me file (similar to the one in ctan page). I was in rush and I couldn't test what `texdoc -l xskak` would show.

Comment: The documentation is on CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf. But it is not in texlive as texlive doesn't include pdfs when the tex file is not part of the package. In miktex you can get the documentation with `mthelp chessboard`. Similar with xskak.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer! I made ​​this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LSB3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\makeatletter
\cbDefineNewPiece{white}{C}
  {\raisebox{\depth}{\cfss@whitepiececolor
   $\bigstar$}}
  {\BlackEmptySquare%
   \makebox[0pt][r]{\cfss@whitepiececolor
   \raisebox{\depth}{%
   \makebox[1em]{$\bigstar$}}}}
\cbDefineNewPiece{black}{c}
  {\raisebox{\depth}{\cfss@blackpiececolor
   $\bigstar$}}
  {\BlackEmptySquare%
   \makebox[0pt][r]{\cfss@blackpiececolor
   \raisebox{\depth}{%
   \makebox[1em]{$\bigstar$}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setchessboard{
  addpieces={},addwhite=Ke4,
  addblack={Cd3,Cd4,Cd5,Ce3,Ce5,Cf3,Cf4,Cf5},showmover=false}
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is nice, but, could it be made with the stars centered in the squares?